# Variable transformation under a discontinuous mapping function introduce different bias?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, random-variable

For any real number $x \in R$, consider its randomized version $y \sim \mathcal{N}(x,1)$. Now consider a mapping function of $y$ denote by $f(y)$.  We want to study the following bias term $R(x) = | E[f(y)] - f(x)  |$. My hypothesis here is that if $f$ is a discontinuous function, then $R(x)$ is not a constant w.r.t $x$. I do not know if this hypothesis is correct, or any condition on $f$ to make my hypothesis correct. If it is correct, can you shed some light how to prove this.

For example, if I choose $f = \mathbb{1}\{y \geq 0\}$ (the threshold function), which returns 1 if $y \geq 0$ and return $0$ if $y <0$,   $f$ is a discontinuous  function at $y =0$. Then for x = -10000 or x = 10000 $R(x)$ should be very small, because $-10000, 10000$ is very far from the discontinuous point $y=0$. However, for $x=0.001$ $R(x)$ should be larger because $x=0.001$ is very close to the discontinuous point.

Thanks

Comment: When $R$ is constant, you should have no trouble showing $f$ must be infinitely differentiable and therefore not discontinuous.

Answer (score 2):

Your hypothesis is correct.

So that we may be notationally clear, let $x$ be a number and let $Y_x$ be its randomized version.  In terms of the density function for a standard Normal variable, $\phi,$ this means $Y_x$ has the density function $y \to \phi(y-x) = \phi(x-y).$  Given any (measurable) mapping $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R},$ in terms of the convolution operator $\star$ we may write

$$E[f(Y_x) - f(x)] = E[f(Y_x)] - f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)\phi(x-y)\,\mathrm{d}y - f(x) = (f\star \phi)(x) - f(x).$$

$R(x)$ is defined to be the absolute value of this expression.  **Suppose $R$ is a constant function $R(x)=r$ for all $x.$**  Then

$$r = R(x) = \pm\left((f\star \phi)(x) - f(x)\right)$$

implies

$$f(x) \pm r = (f\star \phi)(x).$$

**The function $f\star \phi$ is at least as differentiable as $\phi$ is** (because we may differentiate it by differentiating $\phi$ in the defining integral).  In particular, because $\phi$ *is* differentiable, $f\star \phi$ is differentiable, *whence it is continuous.* Since $f \pm r$ is continuous and the constant function $r$ is continuous, so is $f.$

The contrapositive of this implication is

> When $f$ is not continuous, $R$ cannot be constant.

Comment: Thanks @whuber a lot. I think your proof looks quite okay, except the the point where you claim f*phi(.) is at least as differentiable as phi(.). This claim is important for the correctness of the proof. Do you have any backup documents, or more explanation so that it is more convincing.
So here  you meant convolution between a discontinuous function vs a differentiable function is also differentiable ?

Comment: This is a standard -- and very important -- property of convolutions.  I explained the reason why it holds.  Convolution of an arbitrary function (or even of certain "generalized functions") with a Normal distribution is a fundamental tool in mathematical analysis.   See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Properties